# How to configure Dockerfile correctly to run on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to run a Go app using Docker on Google Cloud Run but I'm getting this error:

`Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

I fixed my port to be `8080` as stated in the docs but I think my Dockerfile is incorrect. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
FROM golang:1.12-alpine

RUN apk upgrade -U \
  && apk add \
  ca-certificates \
  git \
  libva-intel-driver \
  make \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/*

ENV GOOS linux
ENV GOARCH amd64
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GOFLAGS "-ldflags=-w -ldflags=-s"
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
RUN echo $PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"
RUN go get -u github.com/cespare/reflex
# RUN reflex -h 
# Setup modules after reflex install
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
  GOFLAGS="$GOFLAGS -mod=vendor"

WORKDIR /go/src/bitbucket.org/team/app/

COPY . .

CMD [ "go", "run", "cmd/main.go" ]
```

Comment: Your program is not listening on the correct TCP port or has failed to create the server. The correct value is PORT and not 8080. It just happens to be 8080 at this time. What port did you configure your application to listen to? In other words, show your code. In your code, you need to read the environment `port := os.Getevn("PORT")` and then use that value for your listener. Also, check the logs for error messages either in the Cloud Run Console GUI or in Stackdriver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dockerfiles don't make your application listen on a specific port number.

The `EXPOSE` directive in Dockerfile is purely a documentation and doesn't do anything functional.

You have 2 options for a Go app:

1. Just refactor your code to read the `PORT` env variable: `os.Getenv("PORT")` and use it on the HTTP server address you’re starting:

   ```
   port := os.Getenv("PORT")
   http.ListenAndServe(":"+port)
   ```
2. Create a `-port` flag and read it during the entrypoint of your app in the Dockerfile:

   e.g. if you can make `go run main.go -port=8080` work, change your dockerfile to:

   ```
   exec go run main.go -port=$PORT
   ```

These will get you what you want.

Ideally you *should not* use `go run` inside a container. Just do:

```
RUN go build -o /bin/my-app ./my/pkg
ENTRYPOINT /bin/my-app
```

to compile a Go program and use it directly. Otherwise, every time **Cloud Run** starts your container, you would be re-compiling it from scratch, which is not fast, this will increase your *cold start* times.

---

Aside from these you seem to have a lot of inconsistencies in your dockerfile.  You set a lot of Go env vars like GOOS GOARCH but you don't actually `go build` your app (`go run` is an on-the-fly compilation and doesn't take the linker flags in GOFLAGS into account I believe). Look at sample Go dockerfiles to have a better idea on how to write idiomatic Go dockerfiles.

Comment: You sent me on the right path and I'm so close! Thank you! I'm stilling getting the error but I know it's because I'm point `CMD` to the incorrect executable...the one I built locally to `bin/app-name`. Do you know the path of the executable after it's built in Cloud Build using `go install  -v ./...`

Comment: I found out the answer so hopefully this helps someone. I found [this article](https://pocketgophers.com/go-install-vs-go-build/) that states what `go install` does (which I added to my Dockerfile). It creates the binary and places it inside `$GOPATH/bin` which turned out to be `/go/bin` inside the docker container. So my CMD command inside the Dockerfile is now `CMD [ "/go/bin/cmd" ]`, `cmd` being the binary.

Comment: Yes, when you do `go build`, the compiler will create a binary in the current directory, with the name of the package you built. Use `go build -o /path/to/bin PKG` to build binaries into a custom directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the `EXPOSE` in  your Dockerfile. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: EXPOSE doesn't do anything functional, it's just documentation.